# A problem with wrapping array algorithm into a function

Tags: r

I just started programming in R. I'm working at code which execute operations on arrays. It works when I put there a variable but if i wrap it into a function something is wrong. When I try to recall list_matrices[i] i got NULL.

```
F <- function(x){
list_matrices=c()
 for(i in 1:dim(x)[1]){
list_matrices[[i]] <- t(rbind(x[i,1:dim(x)[2],1:dim(x)[3]]))}
}
```

Comment: i think you have to define `list_matrices` as list and not as array... something like `list_matrices = [None] * 10`... where `10` is your desired length.

Comment: Maybe try adding `return(list_matrices)` at the end of the function and call `list_matrices  <- F(x)`.

Comment: `list_matrices <- lapply(1:dim(x)[1], function(i) x[i, , ])`

Answer (score 0):

It has already been pointed out in the comments that the problem is that the function does not return `list_matrices` so here we will point out that there is some question of whether you really need to do this in the first place.  If the reason to create the list is to later iterate over it with some function `g`, it would be possible to do that directly over 'x' using `apply`.  These two are the same:

```
# test inputs
x <- array(1:24, 2:4)
g <- function(x) sum(x*x)

# 1
f <- function(x) {
  list_matrices <- c()
  for(i in 1:dim(x)[1]) {
    list_matrices[[i]] <- t(rbind(x[i,1:dim(x)[2],1:dim(x)[3]]))
  }
  list_matrices
}
L <- f(x)
sapply(L, g)
## [1] 2300 2600

# 2
apply(x, 1, g)
## [1] 2300 2600
```

Also note that `F` is used for `FALSE` in R and could result in subtle errors if used as the name of an object so above we have renamed the function `f`.